# Matching fixed-format numbers in regex

Tags: php, regex

Quick regex question (since i am horrible at it)

I have a field that can only have either:

`XXXXXXXXXX` or `XXXXXX-XXXX` where X is a real number.

Bonus if the regex works well with PHP's regex functions.

**The Answer:**

Here's the code from **RoBorg's** answer, for those interested.

```
if(!preg_match("/^\d{6}-?\d{4}$/", $var))
{
    // The entry didn't match
}
```

Comment: please clarify - did you mean _any_ real number, or a _specific_ real number.  My answer assumed the latter.

Comment: @Ólafur: Just curious; is there something specific you don't get about regular expressions?

Comment: please consider a better title - XXXXXX-XXXX is not a fixed number, it's a fixed _format_ number.

Comment: Alnitak you are allowed to edit my question as you see fit :)

Comment: @John just little experience with it, but a problem like this just screams regex, RoBorg's answer actually helped me quite in understanding regex more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/^\d{6}-?\d{4}$/
```

That's

```
^     Start of string
\d{6} a digit, repeated exactly 6 times
-?    an optional "-"
\d{4} a digit, repeated exactly 4 times
$     end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly, it'd be something like this:
`\d{6}-?\d{4}`

You may have to escape the hyphen in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific number (the question wording was originally somewhat ambiguous), search for (e.g.):

```
^123456-?7890$
```

If searching for *any* 10 digit number with that format, search for:

```
^\d{6}-?\d{4}$
```

The `?` qualifier after the dash means "0 or 1 occurrences of the preceding entity"